# Can't select checkboxes in Modal dialog

Tags: css, input, checkbox, modal-dialog

Trying to select any of the checkboxes in the modal dialog here: http://ezami.com/ - the one that pops up after clicking the top right ribbon. None of them seem to work. Did a little research and testing using z-index but nothing seem to work so far, only z-index being set is the modal value and that seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this and see if it helps:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Try putting the input field in the  tag like

```
<span><input ..... ></input></span>
```

Comment: This is the tutorial I used to begin with, nothing new there but thanks for linking it for reference..

Answer (score 0):

I have this sample ready for the logic that you want to implement. the image/colour can be anything.[Demo link](http://cdpn.io/bAdqG)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Checkbox</title>
    <style>
  input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
  }

  input[type=checkbox] + label
   {
       background: #999;
       height: 16px;
       width: 16px;
       display:inline-block;
       padding: 0 0 0 0px;
   }

   input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
    {
        background: #0080FF;
        height: 16px;
        width: 16px;
        display:inline-block;
        padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<p>
   <input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing"/><label for="thing"></label>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @web_dvlp_sd check the demo link in my answer again, i have updated it with the same markup structure as you have in you dialog box. I am just changing the colour, you need to change it with the url of the images.

Comment: This is the exact same logic/code I'm using except you took out the span and applied styles to label instead. Tried that in live site no change, still can't select checkboxes inside the modal window. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: i have tried many things, even removed all the styling. if we just remove the display none property and then check the checkbox, it works fine. Its not the issue with z-index either as u said!